# Nullpointer exception on non empty arraylist - android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am receiving a list from an AWS DynamoDB for a particular scan using code below:

```
List<DBMarkers> markers= new ArrayList<DBMarkers>();

markers = mapper.scan(DBMarkers.class, scanExpression);
Log.d("DynDBS::markers recvd :", String.valueOf(markers.size())); //This shows size as 2

for(DBMarkers temp : markers) {
    temp.getname(); //method in my class - get nullpointer here
}
```

Does anyone know how to proceed??

Comment: If you get NullPointer there... field temp is null there. Look no further

Comment: The issue is that you are getting null results in your mapper.scan function. Try logging the "temp" variable itself. I think you will find it output null to logcat.

Answer (score -1):

replace

```
for(DBMarkers temp : markers) {
temp.getname(); //method in my class - get nullpointer here
}
```

with this

```
for(int i=0; i<markers.size(); i++) {
DBMarkers temp = markers[i]
temp.getname(); //method in my class - get nullpointer here
}
```